# In Pandas can I replace the first row as the header?

Tags: pandas

I'm processing a data frame, and there's a challenge in the source where the data frame headers are incorrect. I want to replace the titles with the value in the first row. Here's a example:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':'age', 'c2':'weight'}, {'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

   c1   c2
0  age weight
1  10  100
2  11  110
3  12  120
```

In the above, the headers are c1, c2 but I want to replace them with age, weight. Is that possible?

Comment: It is a little confusing exactly what you have here?  Is this a multiindex column header or a dataframe with two zero index rows?  Can you give code that will generate this dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston I had a mistake in the display, I edited it. it's a regular dataframe, the extra 0 was a error, I manually created it for this example. I did also add some code to recreate within pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `T` then `set_index`

```
out = df.T.set_index(0).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.set_axis(df.iloc[0], axis=1).drop(0)
```